# Fetching only base type objects in nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I'm currently trying to solve a problem. I have a class table inheritance aka table-er-subclass (one main table + several others with additional data). In my app both base object instances and extended objects can exist. Now I want to be able to sometimes fetch only those base objects and sometimes both types. A simple example (both classes are mapped with all of their properties)

```
public class Base 
{
  public in ID {get; set;}
  public string Something {get; set;}
}

public class Extended : Base 
{
  public bool NewProp{get; set;}
}
```

now running hql query "from Base" would fetch both Base and Extedned objects. Is there any way to restrict such behavior to fetch only Base objects?

Comment: Can you post your mappings for these two classes?

Comment: Actually I'm using NHibernate via ActiveRecord, but maybe it will help:

[ActiveRecord, JoinedBase]
public class Base
{
 [PrimaryKey]
 public int ID{get; set;}
 
 [Property]
 public string Something{get; set;}
}
[ActiveRecord]
public Extended: Base
{
 [JoinedKey]
 public bool NewProp{get; set;}
}

Answer (score 2):

with HQL you should be able to use the "class" special property:

```
from Base b where b.class=Base
```

another approach could be to use plain SQL where you have greater control of what you retrieve.

Anyway check the (N)Hibernate docs.

Comment: unfortunately I get message:
NHibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: class of:

Comment: :/ It's working, now. But eventually I came up with answer why it didn't. Base and Extended are in different assemblies. I registered Base but forgot about Extended - when base class doesn't have subclasses - it doesn't have "class" property.

Answer (score 0):

That's the mapping for the above sample (if there's any error forgive me it must be a typo cause the sample runs)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="true"
                   default-lazy="false"
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Base, Test"
         table="base">
    <id name="ID"
        access="property"
        column="ID"
        type="Int64"
        unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">base_id_seq</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Something"
              access="property"
              type="String">
      <column name="somethin"/>
      <joined-subclass name="Extended, Test"
                       table="extended"
                       schema="extended">
        <key column="id" />
        <property name="NewProp"
                  access="property"
                  type="Boolean">
          <column name="newProp"/>
        </property>
      </joined-subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```